# How to Fetch user events using Oauth in Facebook

Tags: events, graph, facebook

I am trying to fetch user events from facebook but I am having some problem witht he request. I can access their profile image and their UID but for some reason when I try to access the events I get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "QueryParseException",
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
   }
}
```

I have an active access token, that's what I am using to access the UID and profile pic but for some reason the events do not show up.

This is my call:

```
<a href=\"http://graph.facebook.com/me/$cookie['access_token']/events\">events</a>
```

my login button looks like this:

```
<fb:login-button perms="user_events"></fb:login-button>
```

It also throws an error after login in.

---

The error is this:

```
The application must ask for a valid extended permission.
The invalid permissions requested were: .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your call url should look like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=[Your oAuth token]
```